# Deploy React JS bundle with Yii code base

Tags: reactjs, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yii

I am looking for a solution to deploy me ReactJS application bundle with Yii(PHP) code base, I am already having an Yii application which is having frontend and backend both, but some of the page I have migrated into ReactJS application, I want to run both application on same environment,

I need help to configure the application and manage the routing also in the same fashion like old application will reload the page and ReactJS based code will run as client side.

Server: AWS
Technology: ReactJS + Yii (PHP)

Any suggestion !!!